# How to assign a value to multiple cells in a n-dimensional array in Octave

Tags: arrays, image-processing, matrix, octave

Suppose I have a 3x3x3 3D-array called A and a 3x3 matrix called B, created like the following:

```
A = zeros(3,3,3);
B = magic(3);
```

My intention is to turn the elements at the 2nd and 3rd positions of A's 3rd dimension into the matrix B, so it would look something like

```
A(:,:,1) =           A(:,:,2) =           A(:,:,3) =

   0   0   0          8   1   6          8   1   6
   0   0   0          3   5   7          3   5   7
   0   0   0          4   9   2          4   9   2
```

My first try was to make

```
A(:,:,2:3) = B
```

But I get the following:

```
error: A(I,J,...) = X: dimensions mismatch
```

It feels strange to me, since, for instance,

```
B(1,1:2) = 10
```

would produce a correct result.

How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comment:  `B(1,1:2) = 10` works because you are broadcasting a **single value** over multiple dimensions.  This is simply syntatic sugar in Octave.  `A(:,:,2:3) = B` will cause a dimension mismatch because you are trying to assign a single slice or a 2D matrix into a 3D matrix.  The dimensions are incompatible.  Therefore, your solution with `repmat` works because the dimensions match up on the left and right side of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget it, I solved it with the following:

```
A(:,:,1:2) = repmat(B, [1 1 2])
```

:)